# Divide multiple <ul> into balance columns

Tags: html, css

I have multiple `<ul>`'s and i want to divide them into three columns with equal heights.

```css
#list {
  column-count: 3;
  column-fill: balance;
}

#list ul {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div id="list">
  <ul>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
    <li>Item 4</li>
    <li>Item 5</li>
    <li>Item 6</li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
    <li>Item 4</li>
    <li>Item 5</li>
    <li>Item 6</li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
    <li>Item 4</li>
    <li>Item 5</li>
    <li>Item 6</li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
    <li>Item 4</li>
    <li>Item 5</li>
    <li>Item 6</li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
    <li>Item 4</li>
    <li>Item 5</li>
    <li>Item 6</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

This logic divides the columns into three. But the columns are not balanced. I want to equally divide the content in all three columns probably with same height. The 3 columns are not balanced. Can we re-balance the columns so first two columns are not so long?Is it possible ?? Any help.

Comment: What do you mean by "balanced" they are already equal height like you asked.

Comment: The 3 columns are not balanced. Can we re-balance the columns so first two columns are not so long?

Comment: I still don't know what you mean by balanced so I'm unable to answer your question.

Comment: I want three columns to have "SAME HEIGHT" i.e, Split List Into Equal-Sized Columns. Content should be distributed equally.

Answer (score 6):

`balance` is the default value of the `column-fill`. The problem is the `float: left`. remove it and you can write it like this:

```css
#list {
  column-count: 3;
  -moz-column-fill: balance;
  column-fill: balance;
}

#list ul {
  margin: 0;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="list">
  <ul>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
    <li>Item 4</li>
    <li>Item 5</li>
    <li>Item 6</li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
    <li>Item 4</li>
    <li>Item 5</li>
    <li>Item 6</li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
    <li>Item 4</li>
    <li>Item 5</li>
    <li>Item 6</li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
    <li>Item 4</li>
    <li>Item 5</li>
    <li>Item 6</li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
    <li>Item 4</li>
    <li>Item 5</li>
    <li>Item 6</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Will delete mine since you were 20 sec. faster :) ..+1.. and no need to use `display: block`, it's their default

Comment: @LGSon oh, Thank you. You are right, block is the default value for `ul`. don't need to be there. it's just for reset if he needed it.

Answer (score 0):

Friend, the following sentence has two layers of logic in it.

> This logic divides the columns into three. But the columns are not balanced. I want to equally divide the content in all three columns probably with same height.

Equal division in columns can be done:

1. Content wise
2. Space wise

If you wish to correct your given example only space wise (remove the ugly gap from the first column) then just add `margin:0;` at the `ul` element (or change the property margin at will).

If you wish to correct both perspectives in your example then @ICE's answer is king (note that `margin:0;` is also crucial in this way).